# What is KEYVAL? And what it's intended for?

Tags: javascript

While reading code from some project, I stumbled on this `KEYVAL`:

```
KEYVAL:
      for(key_name in arg_map) {    // iterates over hash key|value pairs
        // if this key_name belongs to this object, not proto
        if(arg_map.hasOwnProperty(key_name)) {    

          // skip dependent keys during iteration
          if(key_name.indexOf('_') === 0) { continue KEYVAL; }

          // update independent key value
          anchor_map_revise[key_name] = arg_map[key_name];

          // update matching dependent key
          key_name_dep = '_' + key_name;
          if(arg_map[key_name_dep]) {
            anchor_map_revise[key_name_dep] = arg_map[key_name_dep];
          } else {
            delete anchor_map_revise[key_name_dep];
            delete anchor_map_revise['_s' + key_name_dep];
          }

        }  // if end
      }  // for end
```

What is that? What the purpose of this? Is it part of JS syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a label. A label is an identifier (here: `KEYVAL`), followed by a colon (`:`), that precedes a statement (in this case, `for`).

A `continue` or `break` statement can use a label (in your case `continue KEYVAL`) to specify which loop to continue with, or break from. In this case, the `KEYVAL: for` is the innermost loop, so the label is actually not necessary; but labels are useful if you need to break from several levels at once.

See more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue).

EDIT: `for`, not `while`.